# Main thread stops running properly in Cocoa app after a bit when app is inactive

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, thread-safety

I am new to OS X Cocoa and am creating an application that needs to continuously run multiple AppleScripts **while still remaining on the main thread**, as it is not thread-safe to run AppleScripts from any other thread.

---

The problem I am facing is that the **main thread stops running properly** a few seconds **after the app becomes inactive**, thus not executing **anything** on the main thread for minutes while the app is inactive. Whenever the app becomes active again, the main thread starts running properly again until a few seconds after the app becomes inactive again.

I believe the problem arises from Apple's new approach to save battery life and CPU usage on OS X, unfortunately I can't figure out a way to circumvent this.

### Is there any way for me to keep the main thread running even after the application is inactive?

---

***Additional Details***

I am running the rest of the "update loop" in GCD and have restructured my code to run the AppleScripts from the main thread using this method

```
-(void)runAppleScript {
[informationDictionary setObject:[[getTrackIDScript executeAndReturnError:nil] stringValue] forKey:@"currentTrackID"];
}
```

which is being run this way:

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runAppleScript) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];`

This method runs the AppleScript method in the main thread and saves the return value of the AppleScript in a dictionary which I then get with the following code after the method finishes running

```
NSString * trackID = [informationDictionary objectForKey:@"currentTrackID"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at `NSProcessInfo`

[`– performActivityWithOptions:reason:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/performActivityWithOptions%3areason%3ausingBlock%3a)

method (or the equivalent but less straightforward `beginActivityWithOptions:reason:`).

You can pass `NSActivityUserInitiated` as the options argument.

This will disable app napping while the block is executing.

Also take a look at the very interesting WWDC video about [Writing energy efficient code](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I was having trouble finding anything.